# Is this add-on "Extra Lights - Photometric Lighting For Blender" compatible with Blender 2.90.1

Tags: light

Does anyone know if this add-on "Extra Lights - Photometric Lighting For Blender" is compatible with Blender 2.90.1.  Here's the link to this add-on from blender market place:  https://blendermarket.com/products/extra-lights.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is compatible with Blender 2.90.x. At the time of writing, this add-on will work in Blender 2.82 and later. The current version of the add-on can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/jlampel/extra_lights), excluding the presets that are in the paid version.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Yes.  I did hear about the free version in GitHub.  Will you please explain the "presets"?  Are they lights that the creator has set up?  Do most people prefer the convenience of having these presets?  Thanks.

Comment: @YanIronmonger I haven't bought the add-on, but based on the description the "presets" refer to both IES files and defaults for different lamp types. IES files describe the light intensity distribution of a light source, which is basically the light pattern it casts. This is certainly useful when trying to recreate realistic light sources. I can't answer what the general preferences of most users are and whether or not this would be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your opinion.